# How to divide list into 3 sections that are equal in length(sort of) - Python

Tags: python, list

Ok so like lets say a list of length n. n>= 5

I have to choose two index's in the list that will be the cutting point. These 2 elements will be removed as the list will become 3 new lists.

There will be 3 sections: A , B and C.
A must be bigger or equal to B. and B must be bigger or equal to C. The difference between all 3 sections can only be a maximum of one. With these restrictions what is the formula in finding the 2 index's of a list with the length n?

For Example a list with 5 elements. The 2 index's would be index 1 and index 3.

`[1,2,3,4,5] = > [1] [3] [5]` with 2 and 4 being the elements that were removed due to the specific index's being cut.

A bigger list with the length of 19 for example

`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]` The index's that will be the cutting points are index 6 and index 13.

The 3 new formed lists will be `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` `[8,9,10,11,12,13]` and `[15,16,17,18,19]`. You can see that the first two are bigger than the last one as the rules state and the difference in length between each list is not bigger than 1.

Comment: @ozgur I think this question is slightly different when the list is not evenly divisible to equal sizes.

Comment: Have you made any coding attempts at this yourself?

Comment: @ozgur This question is not the same as the dupe. This question involves skips in the sequence.

Comment: Um yea I actually found out with my own experiment. For the first index. I used `round ((len(lst)-1)/3)` and for the second one, there's two possible outcomes depending on the length of the list. if the length is even then multiply the first one by 2 and + 1. If its odd then just multiply by 2. It seems to work with my code.

Comment: @Sait I agree -- this really isn't a duplicate question but is more subtle than the question which it allegedly duplicates.

Comment: @DaenerysTargaryen: Note that `round` in `round ((len(lst)-1)/3)` does nothing in Python 2; and in this case, in Python 3, it would be nicer to rewrite using `//`.

Comment: @Amadan isnt // only the quotient? for example 36 // 10 = 3 but if u do round(36/10) its round(3.6) which is 4

Comment: Yes. But `(36 + 5) // 10` is `4` as well; that is in fact how `round` is implemented in many places (`round(a) = int(0.5 + a)`, at least for positive numbers). The point was that in `(len(lst) - 1) / 3`, both `len(lst) - 1` and `3` are integral, so you are getting an integer (just like `(len(lst) - 1) // 3` in Python 3), and `round` twiddles its thumbs.

Answer (score 0):

```
def split(myList):
    div, mod = divmod(len(myList)-2, 3)
    indices = [div] * 3

    for i in range(mod):
        indices[i] += 1

    parts = []
    for i in range(3):
        parts.append( myList[:indices[i]] )
        myList = myList[indices[i]+1:]
    return parts

print split(range(1,6))
print split(range(1,20))
```

**Output:**

```
[[1], [3], [5]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cut(l):
    i1 = len(l) / 3
    i2 = i1 + (len(l) + 2) / 3
    a = l[ : i1]
    b = l[i1 + 1 : i2]
    c = l[i2 + 1 : ]
    return [a, l[i1], b, l[i2], c]

for i in xrange(6, 10):
    print cut(list(xrange(1, i)))
# => [[1], 2, [3], 4, [5]]
#    [[1, 2], 3, [4], 5, [6]]
#    [[1, 2], 3, [4, 5], 6, [7]]
#    [[1, 2], 3, [4, 5], 6, [7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 0):

A generalization to more than 3 pieces:

```
def findCutPoints(n,k):
    q,r = divmod(n-k+1,k)
    bigSteps = list(range(q+2,r*(q+2) + 1, q+2))
    littleSteps = list(range(r*(q+2) + (q+1),n,q + 1))
    return bigSteps + littleSteps
```

Output:

```
>>> findCutPoints(19,3)
[7, 14]
>>> findCutPoints(34,4)
[9, 18, 27]
```

Note that this function returns the actual numbers from the range [1,...,n] which are removed. The 0-based *indices* of those numbers are 1 less and the function can be easily modified to give the indices rather than the elements. For completeness sake, here is the modified version which returns the indices (e.g. [6,13] rather than [7,14]):

```
def findCutPoints(n,k):
    q,r = divmod(n-k+1,k)
    bigSteps = list(range(q+1, r*(q+2), q+2))
    littleSteps = list(range(r*(q+2) + q, n, q + 1))
    return bigSteps + littleSteps
```